# Groupby returning full row for max occurs

Tags: python, pandas

How to get full row of data for groupby relsult?

```
df
   a   b   c  d   e
0  a  25  12  1  20
1  a  15   1  1   1
2  b  12   1  1   1
3  n  25   2  3   3

In [4]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [5]: df.groupby('a')['b'].max()
Out[5]: 
a
a    25
b    12
n    25
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

How the get the full row?

```
a   b   c  d   e
a  25  12  1  20
b  12   1  1   1
n  25   2  3   3
```

I tried filtering but `df[df.e == df.groupby('a')['b'].max()]` but size is different :(

Original data:

```
0          1       2        3     4        5     6      7       8    9   
EVE00101  Trial  DRY RUN  PASS  1610071  1610071  Y  20140808  NaN  29   

10        11                12           13                 14  
FF1  ./ff1.sh  Event Validation  Hive Tables  2015-11-30 9:40:34
```

`Groupby([1,7])[14].max()` gives me the result but in grouped series as 1 and 7 as index I wanted the corresponding columns. It is 15,000 row data and provided 1 row of sample

Comment: Because you select only column 'b'.

Comment: Yes I wanted to group by only `'b'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `argmax()` :

```
In [287]: df.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.b.argmax(),])
Out[287]:
   a   b   c  d   e
0  a  25  12  1  20
1  b  12   1  1   1
2  n  25   2  3   3
```

This way it works even if `b` is not the biggest one.

Answer (score 2):

I'd overwrite the 'b' column using [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) and then drop the duplicate 'a' row using [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
In [331]:
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('max')
df

Out[331]:
   a   b   c  d   e
0  a  25  12  1  20
1  a  25   1  1   1
2  b  12   1  1   1
3  n  25   2  3   3

In [332]:    
df.drop_duplicates('a')

Out[332]:
   a   b   c  d   e
0  a  25  12  1  20
2  b  12   1  1   1
3  n  25   2  3   3
```

Comment: You'd have to provide data so that I can reproduce, one possibility is you have `NaN` values perhaps, `transform` is designed to return a Series aligned with the original df, it's unclear how it can generate more rows that the original df

Comment: Hi thanks EdChum, but i get this error `Length mismatch: Expected axis has 14793 elements, new values have 15279 elements` in my actual data what could be the reason?  And It doesn't always return the row where max value occurs?

Comment: just a thought does it work if you try `df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(pd.Series.max)`?

Comment: No worries I think Colonel Beauvel's answer is semantically the correct and simpler method